# Powerpivot: Joining historicals for database and forecast from a calculated linked table in a single pivottable

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, powerpivot

I noticed a few people have tried to do similar things that I am asking below. I may have a suggestion in my answer as to how I fix it so i'll ask the question first.

I have historical data that I source from a datawarehouse connection and load into Powerpivot:

```
Date         Store    Sales    NumTransactions   Tag
2010-01-01   A        20000    50                Historical
2010-01-01   B        15000    10                Historical
2010-01-01   C        5000     3                 Historical
2010-01-01   D        300000   500               Historical
```

That connection to Powerpivot is a direct connection to the database server.

And from this data, i calculate a forecast, within excel that spits out a table that is then brought into PowerPivot using a linked table.

```
Date         Store    Sales    NumTransactions   Tag
2010-01-02   A        20010    51                Forecast
2010-01-02   B        16000    12                Forecast
2010-01-02   C        6000     5                 Forecast
2010-01-02   D        400000   650               Forecast
```

From this I want to be able to drive a number of pivot tables and charts which show both sets of data together:

```
Date         Store    Sales    NumTransactions   Tag
2010-01-01   A        20000    50                Historical
2010-01-01   B        15000    10                Historical
2010-01-01   C        5000     3                 Historical
2010-01-01   D        300000   500               Historical
2010-01-02   A        20010    51                Forecast
2010-01-02   B        16000    12                Forecast
2010-01-02   C        6000     5                 Forecast
2010-01-02   D        400000   650               Forecast
```

How do i make this happen? I cant seem to make a relationship work as there is multiple dates and multiple store records.

I have tried to join the two together at within Powerpivot in Table Properties -> Query Editor:

```
SELECT [daily].* FROM [daily]
UNION ALL
SELECT [fcst].* from [fcst]

(Where [daily] is the historical data from the datawarehouse and [fcst] is the linked table within the excel workbook that has been linked into powerpivot)
```

But the problem is that Powerpivot is looking for [fcst] from the Connection that goes back to the datawarehouse where my historicals are coming from.

I can make a work around of driving two pivot tables out of the two data sources and then link them together into one table in excel by directly referencing the cells of the pivot tables (and then drive charts off that). But its messy, and Im sure this can be done. I just cant figure out how.

Does the answer lie in a Set defined by MDX?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do you try to combine data connection from database and excel? maybe if you had the first connection in excel and then create this second connection to union both tables from excel..

Comment: @deathApril I am trying to do that but when I go into table menu -> table properties and then edit the query on the database connection, I can't reference the linked table. Ive tried referencing the table as [forecast] and [forecast$] but each time I do, it tries to fid forecast in the database connection...

Comment: create a new file with data connection to excel and look at the from clause - i don't have excel on this computer, but it looks like `['C:\folder\filename.xlsx'].['Sheet 2']`

Comment: Yeah it can be done that way, but I want to keep it as one file so that t can be shared around the organisation easily. There must be a way to refer to a linked table in the table query statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PowerPivot creates a relationship, it needs one table to have a column with distinct values that you use as a lookup column for another table. I would suggest that you create a date table. You can get one from https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/1542c52d-d466-4094-a801-9ef8fd7c6485 if you don't have an easy way to create one. Then you can create a relationship from daily to date and from fcst to date. I would also add a calculated column to daily with just a string "Historical" and add a calculated column to fcst for a string "Forecast". Add another linked table with two rows in it: Historical, Forecast. Then create a relationship from daily to this linked table. If you create a flattened PivotTable with all this in place - you can get close to what you're looking for, but you're probably going to have one column for sales for historical and another column for sales for forecast. You can create a measure in one of the tables (doesn't matter which one) to use conditional logic to use the applicable value based on the current tag and just use that in your PivotTable instead. Do the same for the number of transactions.

Comment: Great idea! I've got the relationship working now, but I'm having difficulty getting a measure to merge the two sales columns. I have a fcst_flag in both tables where it is 1 for the forecast. I've tried =IF(VALUES(historical[fcst_flag]=1, VALUES(forecast[sales]), VALUES(historical[sales]) but I still only get the Historical sales... Thanks!

Comment: Actually - thinking through this a bit more - I don't think you need to bother with conditional logic. You should be able to create a measure like this: =sum(forecast[sales]) + sum(historical[sales]). That way one or the other will be null as long as you include the column based on the new linked table (historical/forecast) and the measure should then calculate either forecast sales or historical sales. If this works, get rid of fcst_flag.

Comment: Thank you! It works! That has saved me so much time.. You are a saint!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a table of month end dates that is not linked to any other tables and use that date as a slicer with Dates equal to or less than the Slicer, select Actuals and Dates greater than the Slicer, use the Forecast. In doing this you avoid picking up a partial month of actuals for an incomplete month. Then add a measure such as...

```
calculate(sum(historical[sales], filter(historical[date]<=max(monthend[Dates]))) + calculate(sum(forecast[sales], filter(forecast[sales]> max(monthend[Dates])))
```